# Spring Data Rest Pageable Child Collection

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have an @Entity called User. It has a Set of Changesets as follows:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
private Set<Changeset> changesets = new HashSet<Changeset>();
```

I have a UserRepository:

```
@Repository
@RestResource(path = "users", rel = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{ }
```

And a ChangesetRepository:

```
@Repository
@RestResource(path = "changesets", rel = "changesets")
public interface ChangesetRepository extends JpaRepository<Changeset, Long> { }
```

Calling GET on `http://localhost:8080/changesets/` or `http://localhost:8080/users/` yields a paged response.

If I call GET on `http://localhost:8080/users/1/changesets` then I get all the results in a single array and no paging occurs.

Is there a way to indicate to Spring Data Rest that I want to return the changesets collection in a pageable manner when accessing it through its parent User? The Set of changesets will grow quickly and I'd rather not return tons of results in a single page.

EDIT:

As suggested by Willie Wheeler I added this to my ChangesetRepository to make it searchable:

```
@RestResource(path = "byUser", rel = "byUser")
public Page<Changeset> findByUser(@Param("id") User user, Pageable p);
```

I left the relationship bidirectional, but was also able to hide the link to changesets from a user by using `@RestResource(exported=false)` on the Set of changesets.

Side Note: It appears that setting the relationship to exported=false hides the link, but doesn't actually remove the mapping. /users/1/changesets isn't advertised, but it's still valid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that SDR directly supports the approach you describe.

There's another approach you might take though. Instead of using a bidirectional relationship between `Person` and `Changeset`, make it unidirectional from the `Changeset` to the `Person`. Then in your `ChangesetRepository` include a method like this:

```
@RestResource(path = "find-by-person")
Page<Changeset> findByPerson(@Param("person") Person person, Pageable pageable);
```

(I'm just doing that from memory, so you might require minor adjustments.)

From a design perspective I think this is stronger anyway, since I imagine that a person's changesets are relevant in a limited number of contexts. It might be more appropriate to query for changesets rather than bundling them with the person.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I actually implemented it and it's pretty nice. I'll edit my post with details!

Comment: I will accept your answer. Just wanted to see if anyone else came trough with some SDR specific setting that enabled what I wanted.

Comment: Should use `Page<Changeset>` as return type instead of `List<Changeset>`

Comment: It did not work for me, not sure why, I added a method in the repository and tried several combinations of path and rel...

Comment: @HatemJaber make sure you're using the `/search/` sub path.