# href link retrieves a not paginated json - spring data rest jpa

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, hateoas, hal

I've started working on a REST API using Spring. I'm using the tutorial project gs-accessing-data-rest-initial, which is easy to dowload via Spring Tool Suite, in order to get some stuff working as soon as possible.

I've exposed two related entities (aplicacion and registros_app), using PagingAndSortingRepository and annotated both with @RepositoryRestResource, which enables me to expose entities correctly. The result I'm getting when I query on aplicacion is

```
 **GET http://localhost:8090/aplicacion**
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "aplicacion" : [ {
      "nombre" : "app1",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/2"
        },
        "registrosApp" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/2/registrosApp"
        },
        "tipoRegistrosApp" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/2/tipoRegistrosApp"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "nombre" : "app2",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/1"
        },
        "registrosApp" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/1/registrosApp"
        },
        "tipoRegistrosApp" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/1/tipoRegistrosApp"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Which is exactly what I've expected to obtain. So, I was expecting to get the same when I navigate to registrosApp, in terms of pagination; however, when I perform a get on any registrosApp link, what I retrieve from the query is

```
**GET http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/2/registrosApp**

{
  "_embedded" : {
    "registrosapp" : [ {
      "datos" : "{\"FechaInicio\":\"2014-09-16 18:08:44\",\"UsoMemoria\":\"UsedMemory:3 FreeMemory:491 Total Memory:495 Max Memory:989 \",\"InfoPool\":\"Active: 2\"}",
      "fecha_hora" : "2014-09-17T14:04:07.000+0000",
      "codTipoRegistro" : 1,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/registrosApp/605"
        },
        "aplicacion" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/registrosApp/605/aplicacion"
        }
      }
    },{
      "datos" : "{\"FechaInicio\":\"2014-09-16 18:08:44\",\"UsoMemoria\":\"UsedMemory:3 FreeMemory:491 Total Memory:495 Max Memory:989 \",\"InfoPool\":\"Active: 2\"}",
      "fecha_hora" : "2014-09-17T14:04:07.000+0000",
      "codTipoRegistro" : 1,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/registrosApp/667"
        },
        "aplicacion" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/registrosApp/667/aplicacion"
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Which is not actually paginated. I need to get a paginated json when I navigate across links because registrosApp table grows very quickly. ¿What can I do about it?

Here is the code for my registrosApp and aplicacion repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "registrosapp", path = "registrosApp")
public interface RegistrosAppRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<RegistrosApp, Long> {

}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "aplicacion", path = "aplicacion")
public interface AplicacionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Aplicacion, Long> {

//List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

And those are the entities I've defined

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "registros_app")
public class RegistrosApp {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long idRegistrosApp;
    private String datos;
    private Date fecha_hora;
    private long codTipoRegistro;
    public long getCodTipoRegistro() {
        return codTipoRegistro;
    }
    public void setCodTipoRegistro(long codTipoRegistro) {
        this.codTipoRegistro = codTipoRegistro;
    }
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idAplicacion", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Aplicacion aplicacion;
    // private long idAplicacion;
    /*
     * public long getRegistros_app() { return idAplicacion; }
     * 
     * public void setRegistros_app(long registros_app) { this.idAplicacion =
     * registros_app; }
     */
    public String getDatos() {
        return datos;
    }
    public void setDatos(String datos) {
        this.datos = datos;
    }
    public Date getFecha_hora() {
        return fecha_hora;
    }
    public void setFecha_hora(Date fecha_hora) {
        this.fecha_hora = fecha_hora;
    }
}

@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Aplicacion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long aplicacionId;

    private String nombre;
    //relaciones uno a varios
    //relacion con la tabla registros_app
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idAplicacion", nullable = false)
    private Set<RegistrosApp> registrosApp = null;
    //relacion con la tabla tipo_registro_app
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idApp", nullable = false)
    private Set<TipoRegistrosApp> tipoRegistrosApp = null;
    public Set<TipoRegistrosApp> getTipoRegistrosApp() {
        return tipoRegistrosApp;
    }
    public void setTipoRegistrosApp(Set<TipoRegistrosApp> tipoRegistrosApp) {
        this.tipoRegistrosApp = tipoRegistrosApp;
    }
    @JsonProperty
    public Set<RegistrosApp> getRegistrosApp() {
        return registrosApp;
    }
    /**
     * Sets list of <code>Address</code>es.
     */
    public void setRegistrosApp(Set<RegistrosApp> rapps) {
        this.registrosApp= rapps;
    }
    @JsonProperty
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

You can notice that I have a @onetomany annotation between aplicacion and registrosapp in my entities.

TL;DR When I query directly on registrosapp I get a paginated result as I expect. The problem here is when I navigate between related entities, I'm not getting the pagination information I need. ¿What can I do in order to get pagination when I navigate across entities? Any help with this will be truly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer myself in order to get this question useful for someone else who is struggling with this problem. This answer is closely related to - [Spring Data Rest Pageable Child Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469538/spring-data-rest-pageable-child-collection) -

What I've done is to set a method within RegistrosAppRepository, so it stays like this

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "registrosapp", path = "registrosApp")
public interface RegistrosAppRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<RegistrosApp, Long> {

    @RestResource(path = "byAplicacion", rel = "byAplicacion")
    public Page<RegistrosApp> findByAplicacion(@Param("aplicacion_id") Aplicacion aplicacion, Pageable p);

}
```

Then I hide the link to registrosApp which appears in aplicacion, by setting the annotation  `@RestResource(exported=false)` before the Set of registrosApp. So the aplicacion entity stays like this

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Aplicacion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long aplicacionId;

    private String nombre;

    //relaciones uno a varios
    //relacion con la tabla registros_app
    @RestResource(exported=false)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idAplicacion", nullable = false)
    private Set<RegistrosApp> registrosApp = null;

    //relacion con la tabla tipo_registro_app
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idApp", nullable = false)
    private Set<TipoRegistrosApp> tipoRegistrosApp = null;



    public Set<TipoRegistrosApp> getTipoRegistrosApp() {
        return tipoRegistrosApp;
    }

    public void setTipoRegistrosApp(Set<TipoRegistrosApp> tipoRegistrosApp) {
        this.tipoRegistrosApp = tipoRegistrosApp;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

finally, I'm able to navigate between those entities this way:

```
**GET http://localhost:8090/registrosApp/search/byAplicacion?aplicacion_id=2&page=1&size=1**
{
  "_links" : {
    "next" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8090/registrosApp/search/byAplicacion?aplicacion_id=2&page=2&size=1"
    },
    "prev" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8090/registrosApp/search/byAplicacion?aplicacion_id=2&page=0&size=1"
    },
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8090/registrosApp/search/byAplicacion?aplicacion_id=2&page=1&size=1{&sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "registrosapp" : [ {
      "datos" : "{\"FechaInicio\":\"2014-09-16 18:08:44\",\"UsoMemoria\":\"UsedMemory:2 FreeMemory:492 Total Memory:495 Max Memory:989 \",\"InfoPool\":\"Active: 2\"}",
      "fecha_hora" : "2014-09-17T14:04:07.000+0000",
      "codTipoRegistro" : 1,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/registrosApp/593"
        },
        "aplicacion" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/registrosApp/593/aplicacion"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 1,
    "totalElements" : 56,
    "totalPages" : 56,
    "number" : 1
  }
}
```

and the link in aplicacion doesn't show the registrosApp link whithin the json:

```
**GET http://localhost:8090/aplicacion**

{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "aplicacion" : [ {
      "nombre" : "app1",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/2"
        },
        "tipoRegistrosApp" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/2/tipoRegistrosApp"
        },
        "aplicacion" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/2/aplicacion"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "nombre" : "app2",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/1"
        },
        "tipoRegistrosApp" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/1/tipoRegistrosApp"
        },
        "aplicacion" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8090/aplicacion/1/aplicacion"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that `self` should probably not be a templated uri.